# When did litecoin fork bitcoin?

Tags: litecoin, history, project-fork

I'm looking for the git tag of `Bitcoin` at the time of the fork as well as `litecoin` after the fork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the v0.8 release Litecoin is developed using patches to the Bitcoin code base.

Comment: Was the code completely revised as of 0.8?

Comment: Yes, differences to bitcoin in v0.6.3 were turned into a patch set to the bitcoin code base to be maintained separately.